# My `tabular` env has an extra dot in it

Tags: tables, hhline

This table is meant to have three sections that appear to float: the top row, the left column, and the body. This is what I have so far. While it mostly works, there is a dot in the top-left corner that should not be there. Is there a way to remove this?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}

\usepackage{hhline}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{|l||c|c|c|}
        \hhline{~|---}
        \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} &  &  &  \\
        \hhline{-::===}
         &  &  &  \\
        \hhline{-||---}
         &  &  &  \\
        \hhline{-||---}
         &  &  &  \\
        \hhline{-||---}
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You focused so much on personifying the dot that you didn't explain your problem well.  Based on the solution image, I would have phrased it as "I'm trying to create a table where the header row and leading column are visibly separated from the body of the table.  But I'm getting a dot in the upper left where the lines would have intersected."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution (which works only if your background is white).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{|l||c|c|c|}
        \hhline{~|---}
        \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} &  &  &  \\
        \hhline{->{\arrayrulecolor{white}}:>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}:===}
        \noalign{\vspace{-\arrayrulewidth}}
         &  &  &  \\
        \hhline{-||---}
         &  &  &  \\
        \hhline{-||---}
         &  &  &  \\
        \hhline{-||---}
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: what's the difference between `\usepackage{colortabl}` and `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}`?

Comment: `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` loads `xcolor` and `colortbl` (and, *afaik*, activates the command `\rowcolors`). With `\usepackage{colortbl}`, `xcolor` is not loaded.

Comment: WAIT! Instead of white, what about `\thepagecolor`?

Comment: Why not... but one may have constructed the table in colored box...

Comment: oh… I have none

Answer (score 4):

Possibly unavoidable with standard `hhline` methods. On the other hand, a phantom column does the job.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{hhline,array}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|@{}wc{\doublerulesep}@{}|c|c|c|}
\hhline{~~|---|}
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} &  &  &  &  \\
\hhline{~~|---|}
\noalign{\vskip\doublerulesep}
\hhline{|-|~|---|}
&  &  &  & \\
\hhline{|-|~|---|}
&  &  &  & \\
\hhline{|-|~|---|}
&  &  &  & \\
\hhline{|-|~|---|}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It works, but not the best solution in my opinion

Comment: @Someone Perhaps, but certainly painting the dot white is just sweeping the dirt under the rag.

Comment: Most people don't care to look there, and it works…